# What is the theoretical distribution for this AR(1) model, $(1−0.8B)x_t=ϵ_t,ϵ_t∼N(0,1)$?

Tags: time-series, distributions, mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation, autoregressive

The AR(1) model is:

$(1−0.8B)x_t=ϵ_t , ϵ_t∼N(0,1)$   and the true mean of the process is $μ≡E(x_t)=0$.

Please tell me what is the theoretical distribution under the true AR(1) model.

Is it also $N(0,1)$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\epsilon_t$ are i.i.d. samples from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, but that's not the case for your process.

Your process has some time dependencies: the value of $X_t$ depends on $X_{t-1}$ and some white noise. It then makes sense to study the distribution of $X_t | X_{t-1}=x_{t-1}$ (1 past sample since your process is AR(1)), which for your process is $\mathcal{N}(0.8x_{t-1},1)$.

Now if you want to express $X_t$ without taking into account the past, you have to find the stationary solution of your process. This is unique and has the form
$$ X_t=\sum_{j=0}^\infty 0.8^j \epsilon_{t-j} $$

But for time series it is in general more informative to take a look at the mean and the covariance function.